# The possiblity of one more raindrops drop the ground exact same time?

Tags: probability, approximations

Think there is a simple rain and we have got a very very sensitive clock. Is it possible to at least two raindrops hit to ground exact in same time? I mean the date time when they hit the ground, not the flying time.

Comment: This happens with probability zero, but of course probability-zero events happen all the time.  What would make you think it might be impossible?

Comment: In which case this wouldn't be *possible*?

Comment: @WillO Why do you say "probability-zero events happen all the time"? Why then call them probability-zero events?

Comment: @Deep:  To answer your first question:  whenever there are uncountably many possibilities, you can't assign positive probabilities to all of them.  (Proof:  Let $(\epsilon_i)$ be a sequence of positive numbers converging to zero; then there exists an $i$ such that uncountably many of your events are assigned a probability greater than $\epsilon_i$; therefore there can be  no reasonable sense in which your probabilities add to $1$.)   To answer your second question:  They are called probability-zero events because they occur with probability zero.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on: A) what you mean by "exactly the same time" and B) how many rain drops fall during the experiment, and C) how long the experiment runs.

Let's say that if two drops hit the ground within one nanosecond of each other, we'll call that "exactly the same time".  And, let's say that we let a billion raindrops fall in one second.  In that case, there is a likelihood of very nearly 100% that at least two raindrops will fall within one of the one-nanosecond intervals of the experiment.  But if the billion raindrops fall in 1000 seconds, the likelihood is slightly lower.

You haven't asked *how* to calculate the probability, but it's pretty straightforward: There are $10^{12}$ 1-nanosecond timeslots in 1000 seconds.  How many $(N_{no-hit})$ of the $(10^{12})^{1000000000}$ ways the $1000000000$ raindrops can be arranged in the time slots have no rain drops landing in the same timeslot?  The probability that two *will* hit in the same time slot is 1 minus the ratio of $N_{no-hit}$ to $(10^{12})^{1000000000}$.

Note: the above analysis ignores the fact that a raindrop falling near the end of a 1-nanosecond time slot would still fall within 1 nanosecond of another raindrop falling near the beginning of the next time slot.  So the likelihood that two drops will fall at "exactly the same time" is actually much closer to 100% than the above analysis indicates.

Answer (score 0):

Infinitely precise measurements are a myth. If we found the two raindrops that all observers agreed had the largest overlap in their collision times, then we would certainly be running into quantum mechanics uncertainties. But if you chose an arbitrary quantity of time to be practically zero, then you set up the scenario to be inevitable